# How to plot reverse (complementary) ecdf using ggplot?

Tags: r, reverse, ecdf

I currently use stat_ecdf to plot my cumulative frequency graph.

Here is the code I used

```
    cumu_plot <- ggplot(house_total_year, aes(download_speed, colour = ISP)) + 
                 stat_ecdf(size=1)
```

However I want the ecdf to be reversed(complementary ecdf). Any ideas of the easiest way to do this?

Cheers!

Comment: does setting `stat_ecdf(size=1, mapping=aes(-download_speed))` work?

Comment: It doesn't work the way I want :(. What  I want is the value of the y axis to be (1-y) instead of y, so when looking at the plot we can get the information on '...% of the sample has .... or more' instead of '....% of the sample has .... or less'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since seems like there's no easier way to plot the inverse ecdf, here is what I've done in case someone is looking for a solution:

1. extract the information from ecdf function and store it in the new column

   ```
   house_total_year_ecdf <- ddply(house_total_year, c("ISP"), mutate,
         ecdf = ecdf(download_speed)(unique(download_speed))*length(download_speed))

   #transforming the scale to (0,1)
   house_total_year_ecdf_2 <- ddply(house_total_year_ecdf, "ISP", mutate, 
         ecdf =scale(ecdf,center=min(ecdf),scale=diff(range(ecdf))))
   ```
2. Plot the graph using geom_step and with y = 1-ecdf

   ```
   ggplot(house_total_year_ecdf_2, aes(download_speed,1-ecdf, colour = ISP)) +
   geom_step()
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

From the help page of stat_ecdf:

> Computed variables
>
> x
>
> x in data
>
> y
>
> cumulative density corresponding x

So this works:

```
p <- ggplot(dataframe_with_column_Z, aes(x=Z))

p + geom_line(aes(y = 1 - ..y..), stat='ecdf')
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Is there any way to pass a variable instead of the 1? I'm trying to use this to put the ecdf plot on a secondary y axis programmatically, such as `aes(y = ..y.. * var), stat = 'ecdf')`... getting an error when I input a variable, but not when I input the actual number. Thanks!

Comment: This answer works well.  For my use case though I needed to use `geom_step` rather than `geom_line`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you want to stick with that package you can add to aes():

```
y = 1 - ..y..
```

That is,

```
cumu_plot <- ggplot(house_total_year, aes(download_speed, colour = ISP, y = 1 - ..y..)) + stat_ecdf(size=1)
```

In my case I produced the following with:

```
ecdf_gg3 <- ggplot(sim_output_A.m, aes(x=loss, color=plan, y = 1 - ..y..)) +
  stat_ecdf(show.legend=FALSE) +
  labs(
    title="Simulated Loss Output",
    x = "Loss amount",
    y = "Probability of exceeding amount")+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = dollar_format())+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE)+
  scale_color_viridis(discrete=TRUE)
```

[image]